# Connected, locally path-connected topological spaces are path-connected

Tags: general-topology

Prove that if $X$ is connected and locally path connected,
then $X$ is path-connected.

I have to prove that $X$ is path-connected that makes it connected. How to show that for any $x,y\in X$ there is $f:[a,b] \to X$ such that $f(a)=x$ , $f(b)=y$.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove it by observing (why?) that the path-connected components of $X$ are open.

Hence, if $\{\mathfrak P_x\,:\,x\in X\}$ is the set of path-connected components of $X$, then for a fixed $x$ $$\mathfrak P_x=X\setminus\bigcup_{y\notin\mathfrak P_x}\mathfrak P_y$$

Hence, $\mathfrak P_x$ is also closed (because $\bigcup_{y\notin\mathfrak P_x}\mathfrak P_y$ is open). So, each path-connected component is a non-empty clopen. Therefore, $\forall x,\ \mathfrak P_x=X$.

Comment: Thank you, but I am confused with  ∀x, x=X∀x, Px=X.

Comment: Thank you, but I am confused with  ∀x, x=X∀x, Px=X.   I have an idea but I am not sure about it, it is clear that for any x,y belong to U which is open in X there exists a continues function f:[a,b] to U s.t.  f(a)=x and f(b)=y. Then I have to show that for every x,y belong to X there is a continues function s.t. f(0)=x ,f(1)=y.

Comment: @Mado The reason is that $X$ is connected and $\mathfrak P_x$ is non-empty, open and closed.

Comment: "it is clear that for any x,y belong to U which is open in X there exists a continues function f:[a,b] to U s.t. f(a)=x and f(b)=y". Not clear to me why should it be true that "for any open set $U$ and any $x,y\in U$ there is a path in $U$ which connects $x$ to $y$", since it is actually *false* even for $X=\Bbb R$.

Comment: Perhaps you just poorly stated in English that "for all $\alpha\in X$ there is an open set $U$ containing $\alpha$ such that for all $x,y\in X$ there is a path in $U$ connecting $x$ to $y$". This is exactly what the second half of the hypothesis means. I agree that you must *somehow* prove that "for every $x,y\in X$ there is a continuous function s.t. $f(0)=x,\,f(1)=y$", since that's what the thesis means, but I wouldn't call it an "idea" of solution. I would call it being at square 0. In fact, you'll eventually need to use the *first half* of the hypothesis too, which you didn't even mention.